# How to change this behavior of mouse click

Tags: windows, keyboard, click, typing

[image]
So when I click on something, for example, when I click a search result in browser, something appear in that place, you know when you typing something, there's always this blinking black and straight line, that's what i'm talking about, I don't know what that's called.

You can see it in the picture I attach above, the line before the word 'Google'. That line always appear everywhere I click. How do I remove this?

--
You see, when I press end key in my laptop keyboard, usually that takes me to the end of the page, but that's not the case now, I suspect the click behavior i mention above have something to do with this

Note:
I don't know if stackoverflow is the right site to ask this question, but since I don't know any other sites, I just post it here

Comment: Well, I found the solution already, refer to this for more information
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/78208145/line-shows-up-when-clicking-on-text?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution, it's caret browsing from chrome, just press F7 to turn it off. Refer to this thread for more information https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/78208145/line-shows-up-when-clicking-on-text